# How to avoid cast error generated by comparable interfaces

Tags: java, generics, casting, comparator, comparable

I have a generics class in Java:

```
public class PriorityList<T extends Number> implements Comparable<T> {  

    T[] array = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

And I have an error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Number;

Error is make by this casting **(T[]) new Object[10]**.

I need compare methods because I need the array elements must be sorted. So I can't declare class  like this

```
public class PriorityList<T extends Number>
```

Other options which have some sense is make by my own linked list to keep T values. But is another way to solve this casting problem

```
(T[]) new Object[10];
```

?

PS
Collections are forbidden to use.

Comment: @RonDahlgren Speaking of which, I have an old Java book (Java 1.1) that says that you should avoud unnecessary casts and just cast once because storing in a reference and getting the reference takes less time than casting.

Comment: Arrays, generics, and type safety: you can only pick two.

Comment: @gparyani Good point. Depending on his collection's use patterns, it might make sense to keep the an already-casted reference to the head

Answer (score 1):

The erasure of T is Number, so:

```
Number[] array = new Number[10];
```

will get you close enough.  It's okay to store any subclass of Number (e.g. any `T`) in that array. (Note: that also should explain why the cast to `(T[])new Object[10]` aka `(Number[])new Object[10]` would cause the exception.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast array of `Object` into array of `Number` because `Object` array can contain object of any type - not only `T` type. But `new T[]` is incorrect due to type errasure - i.e. java runtime doesn't know about `T`.

One way is to make `a` an `Object[]` array.

Another way is:

```
public PriorityList(Class<T> type) {
    T[] a = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, 10);
}
```

Or, as mentioned - use Java collections - they are more generic-friendly.

Comment: Ok, `Array.newInstance` should meet you needs.. I'm updating some time ago. Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a reserved array to a unknown typed array. I recommend you to use a array factory for T objects in this way:

```
public interface ArrayFactory<T extends Number> {
    T[] create(int size);
}

public class PriorityList<T extends Number> implements Comparable<T> {

    private ArrayFactory<T> factory=...;
    T[] array = factory.create(10);
```

Then, you can provide an implementation of an ArrayFactory to the PriorityList.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Number **is an Object**, but Object **is not a Number**

This method from `java.util.Arrays` contains the logic you want. It can create an array of type T

```
    public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));
        return copy;
    }
```